Does Kiba support BPMN 2.0 based workflow definitions using Kiba framework?
Curious, does / can Kiba support BPMN 2.0 based workflow definitions using Kiba framework? We want to be able to use for describing and executing with confidence various types of process and ETL worklows and need a highly reliable engine that can process these

SpiffWorkflow is a open source python project that is mature, dependable and offers one of the most complete implementations available for BPMN 2.0.
I am a core contributor on SpiffWorkflow
